# What is the difference between USB host VS USB OTG support when it comes to Microcontrollers?

Tags: microcontroller, usb-otg

This microcontroller claims to have USB host, device and OTG support [here](http://www.st.com/web/catalog/mmc/FM141/SC1169/SS1577/LN1877/PF260148).
It is STM32F411CEU6 from ST Microelectronics.

While [this one](http://www.atmel.com/devices/SAM3X8C.aspx?tab=parameters) from Atmel(ATSAM3X8C) just claims acting as USB host and device.

I think any chip that can act as device and host can be used to implement OTG functionality. Am I right? Or the microcontroller should explicitly support the OTG feature?

**PS**: The 2 chips above are just samples and the 2nd says it supports OTG in datasheet as **Jonny_boy** said (yes! bad sample but I can't change it now that it came to this!!). But the question still remains.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic, better suited for http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the datasheet, I'm pretty certain that this mcu would be considered as having usb OTG.  It definitely fits the definition.

Moreover, doing a ctrl+f through the [product series summary](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc11057s.pdf) turns up several registers and pins with "OTG" in the name.  If you look at chapter 12, "Embedded peripherals overview", section 12.9 explicitly says that "USB On-The-Go High Speed Port" is a feature of this MCU.  Please read the datasheet more carefully.

---

edit 1:

As far as the general case goes, Wikipedia is pretty explicit:

> "Use of USB On-The-Go allows those devices to switch back and forth between the roles of host and client devices"

The official usb website, usb.org, has similar (but more verbose) language in its [OTG section.](http://www.usb.org/developers/onthego/)

> The USB On-The-Go and Embedded Host Supplements addresses these scenarios by allowing portable devices and non-PC hosts to have the following enhancements:
>
> - Targeted host capability to communicate with selected other USB peripherals
> - Support for direct connections between OTG devices
> - Power saving features to preserve battery life

We can unequivocally say "yes, a ('non-pc' (whatever that means)) device with both host and slave capabilities is considered OTG.

Comment: The 2 MCUs were only samples. The exact question is Any chip with host, device support can act as OTG as well or not? I will edit the question to be more specific about it